# Immutable data structure replacement for arrays

Tags: java, functional-programming, immutability

What do you use when you need a immutable list with the fastest access/update? LinkedList can be slow if you have to access an element from the middle, and it's prohibitive to create and repopulate it. Binary trees? quadtrees?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "immutable list with the fastest access/update" -- you can't update an immutable list...

Comment: @arshajii It's a common shorthand for "create a new immutable structure with all except one part taken from this existing structure".

Comment: @user2864740 *Which* Haskell data structure are you talking about? `Data.Sequence`?

Comment: If you want fast updates, use a mutable array/list.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No need to be so pessimistic. There are ways to get reasonably fast updates (not quite as fast in practice, but much much faster than linear time) without sacrificing immutability.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i need it to be immutable, so i can safely pass it around threads.

Comment: @WlofrevoKcast I wouldn't do that. Do all the processing you need on the collection in the current thread.  This is usually faster than passing complex data structures or copying them to another thread.  You are not just passing a reference but the data has to be pulled from one CPU's cache to another and the over head can exceed the benefit you get.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not sure what you're talking about, if the cache lines aren't written to (and they won't, as the data structure is immutable) there is no trigger for excessive inter-CPU communication. At least that's my understanding of cache coherency protocols. But let's assume you're right. I still wouldn't say "don't do that" -- the cache has a hard time anyway in a language with only reference types, and even if there was a measurable performance impact the immutable variant probably has a simpler interface.

Comment: There must be a better possible title for this question.

Comment: @delnan The cache lines will be written to if they are updated/copied as the OP states, Java has primitive types as well, and I don't see how an updatable immutable collection has simpler interface than an updatable mutable collection.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that's not what i have in mind. I will have different actors accessing the same list, and sending updates to the updater thread. In short, multiple threads reading and only one making these updates. For a game.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Cache lines are written to once while updating, and during that time no other thread has access. Once the new version of the data structure is published, other CPUs' caches also fetch the cache lines in question, but those cache lines won't get dirtied in the . As for primitive types: Sure, they are there and you can get quite efficient code out of them, but look around, most code is creating objects like there's no tomorrow, including almost every useful data structure. As for simplicity: Yes, "interface" is the wrong term, and I'm running out of space to elaborate.

Comment: @WlofrevoKcast In that case, I would just take an immutable copy as this supports the actor pattern you are using.  The latency hit is worth measuring but could be low enough that it doesn't matter.  If you can concerned about performance, the answer is likely to be to make it single threaded and not take a copy in the first place.  Thread local mutable data often performs the best.

Comment: @delnan I agree with what you have said, there is likely to be so many objects flying around that performance isn't something you want to look at too carefully. ;)  I am used to working on applications where processing a message from one socket and a message out another socket creates less than one object on average. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If updating is very rare (or the collection is small), an array which you don't write to after intialization is worthwhile. The much lower constant factors (both in time and space) outweigh the linear time update in these cases.

Apart from that, there are a number of purely functional data structures which provide better bounds for these cases. 2-3 Finger Trees (the data structure behind Haskell's `Data.Sequence`) are one example. Another option are Clojure's vectors and related data structures (e.g. Relaxed Radix-Balanced Trees), which use trees with high fan-out (32 or more) to keep reads cheap and structural sharing to avoid too many copies.

All of these are moderately tricky to implement manually though, especially if performance is important, and I'm not aware of existing implementations (I don't think Clojure's vectors are easy or convenient to use from Java).

Comment: Thanks delnan. In fact, i've been interested in haskell for a while. Are those data structures used frequently or there exists others approachs when someone used to oop migrates to functional and misses arrays? I'm interested in learning more about functional data structures.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for but I'll try to give a couple of pointers based on some things I've seen in the standard classes:

- [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is a mutable yet threadsafe list because it duplicates the internal array on updates. Perhaps you could adapt some ideas from that, although it's obviously not efficient for large lists.
- [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) implements similar ideas on a much more complicated structure. It divides the internal hash table into separate partitions, so that changes only need to lock access to the relevant partition.

  For an immutable list you could do something similar: divide the list's internal array into several partitions and treat them all as immutable. When you need to change the list, you only need to clone one partition and the index of the partitions, which will be cheaper than duplicating the whole list.
- [AWTEventMulticaster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.html) achieves similar goals, but duplicates the absolute minimum. It's a clever binary tree. See [the source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster-source.html).

With a smaller size of internal partition or block, you can get faster updates, but slower access in general. With a larger block (e.g., the entire array) you get slower updates but faster access.

If you really need fastest access and update, you have to use a mutable array.